# Laravel: Post request keeps getting 302

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am making a post that seems to successfully reach the controller but the browser keeps showing a 302 response.  I am logging the request with `dd()` and am getting the text to log appropriately.  I don't know why I am getting a 302 though.  I posted my code below and would love some input on what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks!

**Blade**

```
<form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/store/custom-text/update') }}">
    <div class="form-group @hasError('custom_text')">
        <textarea name="custom_text" value="{{ old('custom_text') }}">
        </textarea>
        @error('custom_text')
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update Custom Text</button>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\Admin\CustomTextFormRequest;

class CustomTextController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin.store.custom-text');
    }

    public function update(CustomTextFormRequest $request)
    {
        $customText = $request->input('custom_text');
        dd($customText);
        flash('Custom Text Updated!');
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**CustomTextForRequest**

```
class CustomTextFormRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'custom_text' => 'required|string',
        ];
    }
}
```

** Routes **

```
Route::post('admin/store/custom-text/update', 'Admin\CustomTextController@update');
```

Comment: as you have `dd()` in your controller update method what's the current result when you post the form?

Answer (score 1):

**Try including the [CSRF token](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf) in your form:**

```
<form class="form" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/admin/store/custom-text/update') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group @hasError('custom_text')">
        <textarea name="custom_text" value="{{ old('custom_text') }}">
        </textarea>
        @error('custom_text')
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Update Custom Text</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You getting `302` status code, because after some actions you are redirecting back

```
return redirect()->back();
```

If you updating form via ajax request and don't want `302` status code, remove line below and just return some data

```
$data = 'saved-custom-text';
return $data;
```

Comment: what the difference between your cod and the posted code ?

Comment: an answer is a solution right? what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I agree, @keizah is correct.

=> The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing URL redirection

```
return redirect()->back();
// or 
return back();
// brings you back to the previous page which means you are being redirected
```

So the answer would be

**Post request keeps getting 302 because you are performing redirection in your controller, so you will get status 302 instead of 200**

If you think we have misinterpreted your question, maybe you could tell us what status were you expecting? or what exactly did you want to happen

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
flash('Custom Text Updated!');
return redirect()->back();
```

You can redirect the user back with the flash message using this syntax.

```
return back()->with('success_message', 'Custom Text Updated!');
```

Answer (score 0):

check your validator in controller or
`Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest`.

like:

```
    /**
     * @return array<string,array<string>>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
           'some_rules' => ['you_written'],
        ];
    }
```